# Attribute value needed near CSV python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to get the attribute value  JPY near the text(100) in my output . I am aware of attrib function and created one seperately using  lxml ,however I would like to get this working inside my code to get the attribute value near the text value 
This is my input file

```
<pain001><CstmrCdtTrfInitn><GrpHdr><MsgId>ABC/120928/CCT001</MsgId><CreDtTm>2012-09-28T14:07:00</CreDtTm><NbOfTxs>100000</NbOfTxs><CtrlSum>11500000</CtrlSum> <InitgPty><Nm>ABC Corporation</Nm><PstlAdr><StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm><BldgNb>7</BldgNb><PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd><TwnNm>New York</TwnNm><Ctry>US</Ctry></PstlAdr></InitgPty></GrpHdr><PmtInf><PmtInfId>CARCORP/086</PmtInfId><PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd><BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg><ReqdExctnDt>2012-09-29</ReqdExctnDt><Dbtr><Nm>CARCORP INC</Nm><PstlAdr><StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm><BldgNb>7</BldgNb><PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd><TwnNm>New York</TwnNm><Ctry>US</Ctry></PstlAdr></Dbtr><DbtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>00125574999</Id></Othr></Id></DbtrAcct><DbtrAgt><FinInstnId><BICFI>BBBBUS33</BICFI></FinInstnId></DbtrAgt><CdtTrfTxInf><PmtId><InstrId>ABC/120928/CCT001/01</InstrId><EndToEndId>ABC/4562/4</EndToEndId></PmtId><Amt><InstdAmt Ccy="JPY">100</InstdAmt></Amt><ChrgBr>SHAR</ChrgBr><CdtrAgt><FinInstnId><BICFI>AAAAGB2L</BICFI></FinInstnId></CdtrAgt><Cdtr><Nm>DEF Electronics</Nm><PstlAdr><AdrLine>Corn Exchange 5th Floor</AdrLine><AdrLine>Mark Lane 55</AdrLine><AdrLine>EC3R7NE London</AdrLine><AdrLine>GB</AdrLine></PstlAdr></Cdtr><CdtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>23683707994125</Id></Othr></Id></CdtrAcct><Purp><Cd>GDDS</Cd></Purp><RmtInf><Strd><RfrdDocInf><Tp><CdOrPrtry><Cd>CINV</Cd></CdOrPrtry></Tp><Nb>4562</Nb><RltdDt>2012-09-08</RltdDt></RfrdDocInf></Strd></RmtInf></CdtTrfTxInf></PmtInf></CstmrCdtTrfInitn></pain001>
<pain001><CstmrCdtTrfInitn><GrpHdr><MsgId>ABC/120928/CCT001</MsgId><CreDtTm>2012-09-28T14:07:00</CreDtTm><NbOfTxs>100000</NbOfTxs><CtrlSum>11500000</CtrlSum> <InitgPty><Nm>ABC Corporation</Nm><PstlAdr><StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm><BldgNb>7</BldgNb><PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd><TwnNm>New York</TwnNm><Ctry>US</Ctry></PstlAdr></InitgPty></GrpHdr><PmtInf><PmtInfId>CARCORP/086</PmtInfId><PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd><BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg><ReqdExctnDt>2012-09-29</ReqdExctnDt><Dbtr><Nm>CARCORP INC</Nm><PstlAdr><StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm><BldgNb>7</BldgNb><PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd><TwnNm>New York</TwnNm><Ctry>US</Ctry></PstlAdr></Dbtr><DbtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>00125574999</Id></Othr></Id></DbtrAcct><DbtrAgt><FinInstnId><BICFI>BBBBUS33</BICFI></FinInstnId></DbtrAgt><CdtTrfTxInf><PmtId><InstrId>ABC/120928/CCT001/01</InstrId><EndToEndId>ABC/4562/4</EndToEndId></PmtId><Amt><InstdAmt Ccy="JPY">100</InstdAmt></Amt><ChrgBr>SHAR</ChrgBr><CdtrAgt><FinInstnId><BICFI>AAAAGB2L</BICFI></FinInstnId></CdtrAgt><Cdtr><Nm>DEF Electronics</Nm><PstlAdr><AdrLine>Corn Exchange 5th Floor</AdrLine><AdrLine>Mark Lane 55</AdrLine><AdrLine>EC3R7NE London</AdrLine><AdrLine>GB</AdrLine></PstlAdr></Cdtr><CdtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>23683707994125</Id></Othr></Id></CdtrAcct><Purp><Cd>GDDS</Cd></Purp><RmtInf><Strd><RfrdDocInf><Tp><CdOrPrtry><Cd>CINV</Cd></CdOrPrtry></Tp><Nb>4562</Nb><RltdDt>2012-09-08</RltdDt></RfrdDocInf></Strd></RmtInf></CdtTrfTxInf></PmtInf></CstmrCdtTrfInitn></pain001>
```

I have specific tag which has attribute value

```
 <InstdAmt Ccy="JPY">100</InstdAmt>
```

Required output file instead of 100,100

```
JPY,100
```

My code below

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python2.7 python2.7

import lxml.etree
import csv
import sys



compile xpath selectors for element text
selectors = ('GrpHdr/InitgPty/Nm',
      'GrpHdr/CreDtTm',

      'GrpHdr/NbOfTxs',

      'GrpHdr/CtrlSum',

      'GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/StrtNm',

      'GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/BldgNb',

      'GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/PstCd',

      'GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/TwnNm',

      'GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/Ctry',

      'PmtInf/PmtInfId',

      'PmtInf/PmtMtd',

      'PmtInf/BtchBookg',

      'PmtInf/ReqdExctnDt',

      'PmtInf/Dbtr/Nm',

      'PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/StrtNm',

      'PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/BldgNb',

      'PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/PstCd',

      'PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/TwnNm',

      'PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/Ctry',

      'PmtInf/DbtrAcct/Id/Othr/Id',

      'PmtInf/DbtrAgt/FinInstnId/BICFI',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/InstrId',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/EndToEndId',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Amt/InstdAmt',
      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Amt/InstdAmt[@Ccy]',           
      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/ChrgBr',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/CdtrAgt/FinInstnId/BICFI',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/Nm',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/PstlAdr/AdrLine[1]',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/PstlAdr/AdrLine[2]',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/PstlAdr/AdrLine[3]',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/PstlAdr/AdrLine[4]',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/CdtrAcct/Id/Othr/Id',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Purp/Cd',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/Tp/CdOrPrtry/Cd',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/Nb',

      'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/RltdDt')


 etc...
xpath = [lxml.etree.XPath("{}/text()".format(s)) for s in selectors]

 open result csv file
with open('pain.csv', 'w') as paincsv:
    writer = csv.writer(paincsv)
    # read file with 1 'CstmrCdtTrfInitn' record per line
    with open('pain100k.xml') as painxml:
        # process each record
        for index, line in enumerate(painxml):
            if not line.strip(): # allow empty lines
                continue
            try:
                # each line is an xml doc
                pain001 = lxml.etree.fromstring(line)
                # move to the customer elem
                elem = pain001.find('CstmrCdtTrfInitn')
                elem1 = pain001.find('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Amt/InstdAmt')
                # select each value and write to csv
                writer.writerow([xp(elem)[0].strip() for xp in xpath])
              #  x =  (elem1.attrib['Ccy'])
               # print  ",".join('pain.csv'+str(x))
            except Exception, e:
                # give a hint where things go bad
                sys.stderr.write("Error line {}, {}".format(index, str(e)))
                raise
```

My output I am getting is

```
    ABC Corporation,2012-09-28T14:07:00,100000,11500000,Times Square,7,NY 10036,New York,US,CARCORP/086,TRF,false,2012-09-29,CARCORP INC,Times Square,7,NY 10036,New York,U
S,00125574999,BBBBUS33,ABC/120928/CCT001/01,ABC/4562/4,**100,100**,SHAR,AAAAGB2L,DEF Electronics,Corn Exchange 5th Floor,Mark Lane 55,EC3R7NE London,GB,23683707994125,GDDS
,CINV,4562,2012-09-08
```

I need output like JPY, 100 , and want to do changes in the same code and extract the output

Comment: Your question sounds like you want to examine all attributes, which is somewhat complicated; but your examples look like you want the value of the `Ccy` attribute, which is very simple.  Which is it?  Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Only there is a single attribute in the input file and I would like to add it in the CSV format  JPY,100, etc

Answer (score 2):

The attributes are stored in the `elem.attrib` which is a `dict`. Also accessible through `elem.get()`.

All of this can be found from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).